# Is It possible not to use orWhere and use like where['col', 'val' OR 'col_2','val_2' ] in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

Here is my query

```
if (!empty($request)) {
    $members = DB::table('members');
    if (isset($request->search) AND $request->search != null) {
        $members = $members->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
            ->orWhere('contact_number', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
            ->orWhere('nid_number', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
            ->orWhere('id', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%');
    }
    if (isset($request->type) AND $request->type != null) {
        $members = $members->where('done_undone', '=', $request->type);
    }
    if (isset($request->que) AND $request->que != null) {
        $members = $members->where('human_help', '=', 1);
    }
    if (isset($request->q) AND $request->q != null) {
        $members = $members->where('ration', '=', 1);
    }
    if (isset($request->date) AND $request->date != null){
        $members = $members->where('entry_date', '=', $request->date);
    }
    if (isset($request->area) AND $request->area != null){
        $members = $members->where('area', '=', $request->area);
    }
    $members = $members->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(20);
    $total = DB::table('members')->count();
}
```

Here last type is not working, If I use orWhere in search. thats why I asked, If it is possible to make ! where clause without using orWhere, Kindly let me know..

Comment: You just need to group your OR conditions correctly. See the linked answer.

Comment: Can You please write it correctly? I write as you said. but it also get me error. 

```

Comment: `$members = $members->where(function ($query) use ($request->search) {
                    $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                        ->orWhere('contact_number', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                        ->orWhere('nid_number', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                        ->orWhere('id', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%');
                });`

Comment: see. It didn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work". What are you expecting? What are you getting?

Comment: [https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ex2VPZxEu84WhV2mt5rMU1ZULpG9imws]
please see the attached picture. U can understand the error

Comment: I found the error. Thanks a lot. For your Answer